# What is the right data structure for MST in a stream

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, streaming-algorithm

In a single pass stream you can compute the minimum spanning tree (MST) in an undirected graph using the following algorithm:

```
H ← ∅
for each (u,v) in the stream 
    H ← (u, v)
    if H includes a cycle 
            remove largest weight edge in the cycle
```

To make this fast we need a data structure that allows you to check if (u,v) makes a cycle and also allows you to remove the largest weight edge from a cycle.

What is a suitable data structure for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By  noticing that $H$ remains a tree except when $H \gets H \cup (a,b)$ happens,
you can use a ST-Tree[1],  which you can easily modify to support queries of the form "what is the maximum weight edge on the path from $a$ to $b$"

Instead of adding $(a,b)$ directly to $H$ first you check if $a$ and $b$ are connected (using the ST-Tree or a Union-Find).
If they are not, you add it as possible. Otherwise, if its weight is smaller than $max( a \to b)$, you replace with $(a,b)$ the max. weight edge.

[1]https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link/cut_tree